# AC voltage through a capacitor

Tags: frequency, speed, band-pass

I've built a band pass filter to detect speed using a radar motion detector (IPM-165 http://nic.ath.cx/PDF/sensors/radar/CDM324-doppler/InnoSenT/InnoSenT_application_note_III_11_06.pdf).

Using PSpice I have simulated the circuit as well as building and testing on a breadboard. From the radar I receive values of approximately 5.4mV (Vamp) and 21.0143MHz.

There appears to be no AC voltage and therefore frequency after capacitor C1, is there any obvious reason for this that I am missing?

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I'm at a bit of a loss with it.

[image: Circuit]

Comment: A 10u capacitor is too large, consider using 100n instead. The larger the capacitor, the higher the capacitors series resistance and inductance, so for larger capacitors the inductance dominates at higher frequencies.

Comment: Also, if all you’re needing is a band pass filter, consider using an LC filter. Getting op amps that can do what you want at that frequency is going to be difficult

Comment: Which op amp works at 21MHz?

Comment: @JImDearden I’m using an MC33078P op amp based on the amplifier circuit from the manufacturer. Doesn’t seem to be helping much at all seems a huge frequency to go into a circuit

Comment: @jandy12  Is your frequency of interest correct?  A 21 MHz Doppler frequency indicates a velocity greater than 477 000 km/h, according to the app note you referenced.

Comment: Looking at the specs for the MC33078 it quotes the **gain-bandwith** product as 16MHz - not good enough for a 21Mz signal. Also 1nF @ 21MHz is about 7.6 Ohms

Comment: I’ve now used @C_Elegans advice and changed the affected capacitors and now receiving an output of 2.4V and 50-55Hz. So thanks very much for that I really appreciate the help. This frequency was just to mimic the raw output of the radar before filtering

Comment: @JImDearden do you have any recommendations for an op amp? Would the op amp simply not work with this or would it perhaps give false readings?

Comment: @Jandy12 As I said above, op amp's aren't a very good solution for this frequency. Consider using an LC filter, as it will probably be cheaper and give less noise. If you're set on using an op amp, you need one with a GBP at least as high as your f_in * gain, and preferably higher.

Comment: @C_Elegans LC filters aren’t something I have much experience with but I’ll look into that if you’re saying it’s worth considering. Thanks very much again for your help

Comment: "I’ve now used @C_Elegans advice and changed the affected capacitors and now receiving an output of 2.4V and 50-55Hz." - a 10uF capacitor should have no trouble passing 50-55Hz, so something else was afoot (faulty cap, reverse polarity, coincidence?). 100nF is actually a bit small at this frequency [High Pass Filter calc](http://www.trance-cat.com/electrical-circuit-calculators/en/rc-high-pass-filter-calculator.php)

Comment: @BruceAbbott it’s not initially passing 50-55Hz this is the output of the entire amplifier circuit with downgraded capacitor values

Comment: "it’s not initially passing 50-55Hz this is the output of the entire amplifier circuit" - The filter is designed to only pass the low Doppler frequency, not 21MHz. C1 and C5 should be >=1uF to pass 50Hz without attenuation, but best to use non-polarized caps because electrolytics will leak if not biased correctly.

Comment: @BruceAbbott which sort of values would you recommend? The 100nF capacitors make my lower cut off frequency 100x more than intended so will have to sort that out whilst considering the gain of the circuit. For example, if I wanted to keep gain the same as before I’d have to use 470k resistors in series but this affects my gain massively (0.1 overall). So will have a knock on effect on 1nF/150k branch

Comment: "The 100nF capacitors make my lower cut off frequency 100x more than intended" - then use 10uF, but if using electrolytics ensure they have some positive voltage across them (eg. slightly raise the bias voltage on U1's + input so its output voltage is a bit higher than U2's - input).

Comment: @BruceAbbott you’ve been a great help Bruce thanks very much!

Comment: @C_Elegans do you happen to know a value of Zo to accompany the LC bandpass filter calculations? Or if there even is any? It’s a very small circuit and usually associated with transmission lines I believe. Lower and upper cut off frequencies are 48 and 1254 Hz respectively